# get name of array key

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
        "myName":{
                 "forename":"alf",
                 "surname":"cool",
                 "phone":"000000000000",
                 "email":"mail@com"
},.....
```

My code where I can access each key

```
 for (var key in contacts) {
                          if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                var newRow = new Element('li');
                                newRow.addClass('contact');
                                newRow.set('html', contacts[key].forename + ' ' + contacts[key].surname);

                                var innerSpan = new Element('span').set('html', contacts[key].phone + ', ' + contacts[key].email);
                                innerSpan.addClass('details');
                                innerSpan.set('html', contacts[key].phone + ', ' + contacts[key].email);
                                innerSpan.inject(newRow);

                                newRow.addEvent("click", this.setFromContact.bind(this, contacts[key]));
                                newRow.inject($(this.list));
                               // save myName to a variale here!!

                          }
                 }
```

Now I want to save "myName" to a variable.

Comment: And what's the problem you are dealing with ?

Comment: I dont't get how I can save myName from the json in a variable

Comment: any possibility to get the actual text of the key?

Comment: Do you want that in a variable or in a DOM element? Can you clearify the question a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the value of the keys and if the value is "myName" you can save it into a variable.

```
var myName = '';
for (var key in contacts) {
    if(key == "myName")
        myName = key;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, MooTools and ES5 provide `Object.keys`

```
var obj = {
    myName: { }
    yourName: { }
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ['myName', 'yourName'];
```

I would also advise you to use `Object.each(obj, fn(value, key, obj){})` for iterator. see http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Types/Object#Object:Object-each

it gives you a closure so variables are not re-declared and dont interfere with each other.

```
var keys = [];
Object.each(contacts, function(value, key){
    var newRow = new Element('li.contact').set('html', '{forename} {surname}'.substitute(value)),
        innerSpan = new Element('span.details').set('html', '{phone}, {email}'.substitute(value)).inject(newRow);

    newRow.addEvent("click", this.setFromContact.bind(this, value)).inject($(this.list));
    keys.push(key); // avoids extra Object.keys call
}, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Variable with the "myName" object    
var myVariable = contacts[key];
```

**key** variable is a string, such as "myName"

Comment: but I only want the actual text ("myName") of the key, not the whole object

Comment: What do you get if you do console.log(key)?

Comment: Okay, that was a stupid question of me. Thanks your advice with key made it!